# Textbox on canvas in j2me

Tags: java-me, canvas, textbox, midp, lcdui

I am going to make application on j2me using canvas. I want to take textbox or textfield on my canvas.

Answer (score 6):

You can draw a basic textbox and display a string , and when it receives focus, you can switch the view to that particular textbox ,something like this

```
textBox = new TextBox(....);
Midlet.display.setCurrent(textBox);
```

This would create your data entry more robust and save you from the pain of implementing various keyboard issues yourselves

Comment: thanks Azlam for reply
...but i'm using canvas ...so i need textbox...for user input...
u r telling about form...

Comment: I am not telling about form, I am saying is draw a textbox using a rectangle, when that particular rectangle receives focus, switch from the canvas to the particular textbox (which is a Screen) and switch back to your canvas when done

Answer (score 1):

These items are only available for adding to [`Form`s](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17412_01/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html). [`Canvas`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17412_01/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html) is a class for handling lower-level events.

You have to implement your own textbox, and that isn't easy.
Basic textbox would be a rectangle (`drawRect`) with text (`drawString`) inside of it.