# User input in low level graphics Java ME

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I'm currently developing a mobile application with j2me, and I need to get user input from Canvas.

I know a few ways to create custom input in low level graphics but what I basically want is to paint a textbox on the screen and when people click on it they are redirected to the phone's default input, like if you selected a  **TextField** in a **Form**. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good approach at this other question: [Textbox on canvas in j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243982/textbox-on-canvas-in-j2me)

> You can draw a basic textbox and display a string, and when it
>   receives focus, you can switch the view to that particular TextBox.